# Laravel/Vuejs and Pusher Not Connecting to Private Channel on Heroku

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, heroku, pusher

I have a laravel/vuejs realtime application, works on my local environment but when I deploy to heroku /auth/broadcast shows unsual response,
`bootstrap.js`

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.csrf_token
};
const JWTtoken = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`

import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
// import Pusher from 'pusher-js';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

Pusher.logToConsole = true;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
    encrypted: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'Authorization' : JWTtoken,
        }
    }
});
```

In vue.js component

```
 Echo.private(`App.User.${this.user.id}`)
      .notification((notification) => {
       console.log(notification.type)
   });
```

Response from my local environment (Successful)

```
Pusher :  : ["Event sent",{"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"0d5290e189b56045e99d:e2156d7e13673a1e06f0c2b8974655247a55055de1f7eb31022a1a171615cb8c","channel":"private-App.User.4"}}]
```

[broadcasting/auth response from local environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLS0j.jpg)

Error from `broadcasting/auth` on heroku

```
Pusher :  : ["Error: JSON returned from auth endpoint was invalid, yet status code was 200. Data was: "]
```

[Error pusher broadcasting/auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibpwR.jpg)

Any help or suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The auth endpoint response should be a JSON string with an auth property of a value composed from the application key and the authentication signature, separated by a colon `:` as follows:

```
{
  "auth": "278d425bdf160c739803:58df8b0c36d6982b82c3ecf6b4662e34fe8c25bba48f5369f135bf843651c3a4"
}
```

You should check what the auth endpoint is returning.

[Source](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/library_auth_reference/auth-signatures/)

Comment: @doyboy Thanks for the insight, the response is not returning anything. When I checked the response header, is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` instead of `application/json` any suggestion on setting the response headers for the auth...

Comment: As above, the response should include an auth token. Can you share the code that generates and returns the auth token?